# how to take an image from an object and put it in an element in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i created an object so i can display it in a Flat list
the object is as follwos

```
    export const DISHES = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Uthappizza',
    image: 'images/uthappizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    label: 'Hot',
    price: '4.99',
    featured: true,
    description:
      'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Zucchipakoda',
    image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
    category: 'appetizer',
    label: '',
    price: '1.99',
    featured: false,
    description:
      'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
  },];
```

then i created the flat list and it's working taking all the property from the object as i want but i couldn't get a handle on how to display the images fine but it not displaying the images

```
const Item = ({item, onPress, style}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
    <Card image={item.image}>
      <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20}}>
        {item.name}
      </Text>
      <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>{item.description}</Text>
    </Card>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

function Menu() {
  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return <Item item={item} />;
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={DISHES}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to require the image inside the object itself

```
    export const DISHES = [
{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Uthappizza',
    image: require('images/uthappizza.png'),
    category: 'mains',
    label: 'Hot',
    price: '4.99',
    featured: true,
    description:
      'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Zucchipakoda',
    image: require('images/zucchipakoda.png'),
    category: 'appetizer',
    label: '',
    price: '1.99',
    featured: false,
    description:
      'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
  },];
```

Comment: this works i didn't realize i had to require the image thanks

Comment: You are welcome bro, i was having this problem before

Answer (score 1):

You have different options to handle this scenario
If your data is static you can simply require the image when initializing the array

```
   image: require('images/zucchipakoda.png'),
```

And set the image directly as you have done.

If your images are dynamic, you can store it somewhere else and provide the uri instead of going with the require like above.

Lets say that your image is static and you send the name from the server like "zucchipakoda" then you can create a json object like below

```
images:{
  zucchipakoda:require('images/zucchipakoda.png')
}
```

and use like below

```
src={images['zucchipakoda']}
```

It depends on how you plan to take the app forward and where you are going to store the images.